# xml namespace and xml literals

Tags: vb.net, xml-literals

I'm experimenting with xml literals in vb.net and there's something I don't get. Here's a small sample that illustrates the problem. I'm adding two `PropertyGroup` nodes to an empty Visual Studio project. The first one is added as xml literal, the second as `new  XElement`:

```
Imports <xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
Module MyModule
Sub Main()
    Dim vbproj = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
                </Project>

    vbproj.Root.Add(<PropertyGroup></PropertyGroup>)
    Dim xNameSpace As XNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
    vbproj.Root.Add(New XElement(xNameSpace + "PropertyGroup"))

    Console.WriteLine(vbproj)
End Module
```

This code writes the following output:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"></PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup />
</Project>
```

As you can see, the first `PropertyGroup` node contains a redundant xmlns declaration. Why is that, and can it be avoided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be by design, based on reading the MSDN page for [Imports Statement (XML Namespace)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384589.aspx).

The simplest way to avoid it is by using the [`SaveOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces` enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb551441.aspx), which is available in .NET 4.0:

```
vbproj.AddAnnotation(SaveOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces)
```

If .NET 4.0 isn't an option then you might consider cleaning up the namespaces as shown in these two blog posts:

- [Cleaning up your XML literal namespaces](http://msmvps.com/blogs/bill/archive/2007/11/24/cleaning-up-your-xml-literal-namespaces.aspx) - provides an extension method to be used on each `XElement` to remove the namespace.
- [More on XML Namespaces in VB....](http://msmvps.com/blogs/bill/archive/2007/12/09/more-on-xml-namespaces-in-vb.aspx) - provides an extension method that can be used on the root node and remove namespaces from children items by specifying `True` for the second parameter.

Comment: Great! I'm using .Net 4 so this works perfectly for me! Thank you. I didn't know about these SaveOptions.. Not very discoverable :-(